# Wireless related issues on HP machine

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, hp

There was an install fest recently in my college and the iso that was distributed was a customized version of 12.04.3

Now, the iso works fine on machines by Acer and Lenovo, however the HP machines, specifically the Probook 4440s, is not able to connect to the wifi. Infact, the dropdown menu for connections has no `Enable Wireless` option. Additonally, the machine has a button to enable wireless connections and that button is constantly orange ie, it is disabled, however upon booting into Win8, it is enabled.

How can this be solved ?

Issue of missing drivers?

Comment: what about 13.10?

Comment: @rogerdpack, seeing how it was first timers, the LUG out here decided to distribute 12.04, that being more stable.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763621&page=17 mentions some drivers, though that's about all I'm useful for help wise unfortunately...